# How to get proper information about user agent in nginx log?

Tags: nginx, nginx-log

I've used Nginx docs and set access log format.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
```

When I access the site using Firefox I get the following log:

```
192.168.xx.xxx - - [13/Apr/2021:14:52:16 +0200] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 21408 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
```

But when I access the site using Chrome or Opera I get following logs:

Opera:

```
192.168.xx.xxx - - [13/Apr/2021:14:53:19 +0200] "GET /me HTTP/1.1" 200 24062 "https://my-site.com/me" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36 OPR/64.0.3417.92"
```

Chrome:

```
192.168.xx.xxx - - [13/Apr/2021:15:06:56 +0200] "GET /me HTTP/1.1" 200 115426 "https://my-site.com/me" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
```

Did I properly set my Nginx logging configuration?

Comment: You haven't specified the format in your `access_log` statement, so the default is being used. Not sure what you mean by "proper information". User agent strings are almost useless.

Comment: I want to know which browser has accessed my site. How to log that information?

Comment: Nginx is logging the UserAgent Header send from the browser, and that is all you will get. There are libraries that can help you identitiy the browser on that userAgent string.

Comment: This looks OK, The reason why all of them start with [Mozilla is quite interesting](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

Comment: If you want to map the User-Agent for something else you can use a `map` or `njs` to set another variable based on the User-Agent. But I think all monitoring tools nowadays will be able to work with the default user-agent header value.

Comment: This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) is helpful for describing how the user agent is formulated,

Comment: The story posted by @mx0 is quite funny.